# Unable to invoke no-args constructor for interface java.io.Serializable

Tags: java, json, web-services, gson, liferay

i'm trying to call a json web service (in Liferay), in particular a method for uploading a file (add-file-entry), in the params of the request there is an object ServiceContext (https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/src-html/com/liferay/portal/service/ServiceContext.html#line.69), i send this object param as a JSON String, and the json web service must deserialize the json string into a ServiceContext Object.
ServiceContext has an attribute :

`private Map<String, Serializable> _attributes;`

when i put in this map an entry for example :

`servicecontext.setAttribute("fileEntryTypeId", 0);`

when GSON tries to deserialiaze the servicecontext object :

```
    ServiceContext servicecontext = new Gson().fromJson(ServiceContext, ServiceContext.class);
```

he throws the exception : Unable to invoke no-args constructor for interface java.io.Serializable.

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because the Serializable class does not pre-build without any parameters, so it should not be possible to use it for map

```
private Map<String, Serializable> _attributes; //no
```

If you want you can try this trick, it should work but let me know

```
public class Myclass implements java.io.Serializable {
   public Myclass (){}
}
```

after

```
private Map<String, Myclass > _attributes;
```

> I'm not sure it works for your purpose, try it and let me know

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, but the problem is i can't change the ServiceContext Class, it is defined in the jars of Liferay that i use.

Comment: You do not need to do it, because by implementing the Serializable class you can put it in place of Serializable

Comment: well the map "private Map<String, Myclass > _attributes;" is an attribute of the class ServiceContext, so i think if i want to do your solution i'll have to change the ServiceContext class, don't you think ?